# How to implement Google Calendar API with React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-calendar-api

I am having problems implementing the Google Calendar API with React Big Calendar. I can get the two separately, but combining the two is an issue for me.

So far, I was able to use Google Calendar's API to pull events from an public calendar. I am running it using the command 'node .', and am able to retrieve the events in a way (list of json objects) where it is in the appropriate format for the calendar.

[image: Events retrieved from Public Calendar]

I am able to have React Big Calendar run with static, dummy events, but when I try to use the events retrieved from the Google API call, I run into something called ['promisify' issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldWnF.png), and googling did not help. I am trying to run the program using "npm start", and I was commenting out my code and saw that this line: "const { google } = require('googleapis')" is what caused the promisify issue. I'm going to admit that I am new to Web Programming, and don't understand why it would work with node, but not when I use the two

Here is my current code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
import {
  Calendar,
  momentLocalizer,
} from 'react-big-calendar'

const { google } = require('googleapis')
const { OAuth2 } = google.auth

// Setup authorization to our Google Calendar API using OAuth that was setup 'console.developers.google.com'
const client_id = 'client_id'
const client_secret = 'client_secret'
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2(client_id, client_secret)

oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token:'refresh_token'
})
//const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth: oAuth2Client })
const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      events: []
    }
  }

  comonpentDidMount = () => {
    this.getEvents()

  }

  getEvents() {
    const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', oAuth2Client});

    calendar.events.list({
      calendarId: 'primary',
      singleEvents: true,
      orderBy: 'startTime',
    }, 
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      const events = res.data.items;

      if (events.length) {
        console.log('Events');
        events.map((event, i) => {
          let titleName = event.summary;
          let startTime = event.start.dateTime;
          let endTime = event.end.dateTime;
          this.state.events.push( {title: titleName, start: startTime, end: endTime});
        });
      } 
      else {
        console.log('No upcoming events found.');
      }

      console.log(this.state.events);
    });

  }

} 

const calendar = () =>  {
  return(
    <div>
    <Calendar
      localizer={localizer}
      events={this.state.events}
      startAccessor="start"
      endAccessor="end"
      style={{ height: 500 }}
    />
  </div>
  )       
}

export default calendar;
```

Keep in mind that the client_id, client_secret, and refresh_token were purposefully set to those for the sake of this question.